# In what context does the delete operator throw an error?

Tags: c++, inner-classes, delete-operator

In my implementation of a linked-list, my helper function `deleteNode(Node*)` that deletes inner class `Node` instances is throwing a runtime error, by "triggering a breakpoint" in the Local Windows Debugger in VS 2015. I am being careful to match my `new` and `delete` operators. Does scope/reference play a role that I don't realize?

Even if there is a logic error in `clear()` and `deleteNode()` gets passed `nullptr`, it shouldn't throw an error to delete `nullptr`, and then assign `nullptr` to itself right? What is the issue with that delete?

```
class LinkedList {
public:
    LinkedList() : head(nullptr) {}
    ~LinkedList() { clear(); }

    void push_front() {
        head = createNode(head);
    }

    void clear() {
        Node* current_node = head;
        while (current_node != nullptr) {
            Node* next_node = current_node->next; // buffer
            deleteNode(current_node);
            current_node = next_node;
        }
    }

private:    
    struct Node {
        Node(Node* next)
            : next(next) {}
        Node* next;
    };
    Node* head;
    Node* createNode(Node* next) {
        return new Node(next);
    }
    void deleteNode(Node*& toDelete) {
        delete toDelete; // ***VS 2015 puts breakpoint here***
        toDelete = nullptr;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto A = LinkedList();
    A.push_front();
    A.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

I have removed all attributes and methods not relevant to the error. This dummy code still throws the same error.

Comment: Rule of Five: You need custom copy and move operations.

Comment: @dyp I'm unfamiliar with what you are referring to. Could you link me to a resource explaining it or elaborate on that yourself?

Comment: I think it's not related to your problem, but will cause issues in the future if you're not paying attention to it. The phrase "rule of Five", or formerly "rule of three", will lead you to many articles such as http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem lies within your `clear()` function. You see, you *think* that because of the way you've written your `deleteNode` function, all your nodes will be `nullptr` after `clear`. That is unfortunately not true. You copy your `head` into `current_node`, and the copy of head (i.e. current_node) turns into `nullptr` when it gets deleted, but `head` remains non-null. Later the destructor attempts to delete it again. Calling delete on already freed memory results in Undefined Behavior.

To fix, add

```
 head = nullptr;
```

in the end of your clear function

Comment: Thank you. Just to clarify, even though I pass the  pointer by reference to `deleteNode`, since `current_node` is only a copy of `head`, `head` does not get set to `nullptr`. Right?

Answer (score 4):

> In what context does the delete operator throw an error?

A `delete` expression can throw, if the destructor itself throws, or a destructor of a sub object. But you should avoid throwing in a destructor.

A `delete` expression might also have undefined behaviour if you try to delete a pointer that does not point to a valid object. An exception is `nullptr`, which is safe to delete. Typical causes for accidentally deleting an invalid pointer is trying to delete same pointer value twice, or forgetting to initialize memory. Undefined behviour can result in anything, including an error being thrown.

> What is the issue with that delete?

You're deleting the same pointer twice. You can verify that by checking the value in a debugger.